# Django limit the number of requests per minute

Tags: python, django, request

I'm trying to limit the number of requests from an IP in case I get too many requests from it.

For example: if I will get more than 50 requests per minute I want to block that
IP for 5 minutes.

When I use `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` I always get the IP of the local host and not the one that sent the request.

1. How can I get the IP of the computer that sent the request?
2. How can I limit that IP to not send more requests for X time?

Comment: IMO, this functionality should be implemented using the web server you deploy with, not Django. See, e.g.: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Answer (score 13):

[django-ratelimit](https://github.com/jsocol/django-ratelimit) will limit the number of requests you receive over a given amount of time.

#### Install:

```
pip install django-ratelimit
```

#### In your view:

```
from django_ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit

@ratelimit(key='ip', rate='10/m')
def myview(request):
...
```

Comment: Sweet as sugar!

Answer (score 1):

1.how can i get the IP of the computer that sent the request?

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

>>>get_client_ip(request)
"client ip"
```

2.how can i limit that IP to not send more requests for X time?

I think you can setup a `middleware` for this type.SOmething like saving request time in database, compare adjacent request with previous and so on.

**Updated from comment**

If you are using nginx as web server,Try this 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Comment: see @dyleri's comment. no offense but if OP wants to limit the requests per minute, chances are not wanting that IP to interact with the app. However your suggestion will inevitably hitting the database hard for the requests you don't want to deal with, which in my honest opinion, not right.

Comment: Q1 is right? Q2, OP didnt mention nginx is using as webserver?

Comment: your Q1 yes and no, this may not be correct since OP is not specified what stack this is in, not getting request IP can be under many circumstances like behind a proxy server etc. Regarding to dyleri's comment, the idea is not about Nginx but **webserver**.
Even so, you cannot always trust **django** headers to determine request IP.

Comment: @Anzel I acknowledge that the OP asked about doing this in Django, which is why I responded in a comment, not an answer. Nonetheless, I believe that "don't do it that way" is the correct information to provide.

Comment: @dylrei, I agree. And that's why I only comment under this answer but do not downvote even the whole thing isn't right, because this is indeed one way round to answer under OP's requirements.

Comment: Thanks both of you, :) .Am not trying to arguing you, sorry if you feel like?

Comment: Can be nginx http limit request module used for all locations, I would like to kick out dir bruteforcing attempts

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Django Throttling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) which is doing exactly what you want to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use ratelimit decorator in **class base Views** . you have to use method decorator in django . look at this and then like it :

first import method decorator:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
```

and then :

```
class CheckSecureAccess(View):
    @method_decorator(ratelimit(key='ip', rate='10/m', method='GET'))
    def get(self, request, episode_name):
    ...
```