# check if someone "iterates" through urls in django project

Tags: django, security, url, bots

Is it possible, i.e. does some middleware exist, to detect (and prevent) someone from just iterating through url's of my django project?

`https://www.myproject.com/myapp/<pk>`

At the moment someone / a bot could just iterate with the pk from 1 to 1000. Can I stop him from calling more than 10 sites like this within a such and such timeframe?

Comment: Hey! Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326362/18020941

Comment: You "throttle" the number of requests.

Comment: You could add a UUID field to your model and use this in the urls. That would make your urls unpredictable.